# WPF Plugin creating UI strategy

Tags: wpf, multithreading, plugins, background

I have an application with ability to load some plugins (dll's). It's working on WPF. The problem is lags when plugin creates UI controls.

In main application I have some controls. I pass these references to plugin. When I call plugin's Show() method, he must add special UI controls to my main application.

How can I create plugin's UI controls in background thread and add their in main application, if main application UI thread don't have access to any control,s wich was created in another thread?

I use this code in main application:

```
if (!module.IsInitialized())
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        module.InitializeComponents();
                        module.ShowModule();
                    }
                ));
            }
```

where plugin initialize method is:

```
public void InitializeComponents()
{
MyBodyArea = new SERPBodyArea(); // there is UI control
MyBottomArea = new SERPBottomArea(); // there is UI control
 MyHeaderRibbon = new SERPXamRibbon(); // there is UI control

_IsInitialized = true;
}
```

So when plugin creates UI controls, my main application is frozen. Is thre any way to create it in background thread and add it to main application window?

Thanks. And sorry for my bad english :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must continue to construct your controls on the UI thread but you can make them more light weight and streamlined.  Usually this involves deferring some of the initialization of a control (most often the data the control is bound to) to a background thread.  However, the same strategy can apply to CPU-intensive calculations or data structure manipulations.

If the amount of actual work that is done on the UI thread is proportional to the amount of information that is displayed on the screen, then most applications will initialize very quickly.  Your situation depends on your controls so it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In module initialization method, which calls in UI thread, I create only UI controls (data structures, calculations inserted in background thread). Module UI controls are third-party datagrid, ribbon etc. So initialization takes about 2-3 sec with my powerfull PC configuration.

Comment: So if I can't do works in background thread, maybe I can run smoothly loading animation? I tried play it in main application window and no-modal window, but it also frozen (I can see 0-2 key frames, after that animation stops, and main application frozen too for 2-3 seconds , until module initialization is not finish)

Comment: Yes, you can put a whole **window** on another thread while your components initialize.  Here's an article that describes how to create a splash screen that is responsive even when your main window is blocked: http://szymonrozga.net/blog/?p=136